# Getting and setting length of arbitrary slice

Tags: go

To get length of any slice, I use `reflect.ValueOf(slice).Len()`.
To set length of any slice, I use `reflect.ValueOf(&slice).Elem().SetLen(n)`.

I have a field of type `reflect.Value` in my struct, and the value is set to be `reflect.ValueOf(&slice)` so that I can change the slice. But now I can't get the length of the underlying slice.

It would panic because of `call of reflect.Value.Len on ptr Value` if I call `Len()` directly, and `call of reflect.Value.Len on interface Value` if I call `Elem().Len()`.

Below is the function I was trying to implement:

```
func pop(slice interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    length := v.Len()
    last := v.Index(length - 1)
    v.SetLen(length - 1)
    return last
}
```

How can I do both with `refect.Value` of the slice pointer?

Comment: It sounds like your `slice` isn't actually a slice. It looks like some kind of interface wrapper around a slice.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that the slice is stored in a argument of type `interface{}`.

Comment: @iLoveReflection Thx. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the function to work with a pointer to slice argument.

```
// pop removes and returns the last element from
// the slice pointed to by slicep.
func pop(slicep interface{}) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slicep).Elem()
    length := v.Len()
    last := v.Index(length - 1)
    v.SetLen(length - 1)
    return last
}
```

Call it like this:

```
slice := []int{1, 2, 3}
last := pop(&slice)
fmt.Println(last)  // prints 3
fmt.Println(slice) // prints [1 2]
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IIeUNtTFgxM)